# Is it possible to change UITextInputTraits while a UIKeyboard is in view?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, textinput

I want to change the UITextInputTraits of a keyboard while it is in use....

My *ideal* code would look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)nameTextDidChange:(UITextField *)sender {
    if ([sender.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        sender.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    } else {
        sender.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
    }
}
```

So... I have a different 'Return' button for an empty string as I do a string with some text in. The code I posted above doesn't work, the keyboard retains it's original text input traits.

Any ideas anyone, or is this never going to work no-matter how hard I try?

Cheers!

Nick.

Thanks to Deepak, this is the code I actually used:

```
if ([sender.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    sender.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    [sender becomeFirstResponder];
} else if (sender.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyDone) {

    NSString *cachedLetter = sender.text;

    sender.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;

    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    [sender becomeFirstResponder];

    sender.text = cachedLetter;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make this work by adding the following lines at the end of the method.

```
if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
} else if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyDone) {
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

This should work.

You basically flip it on and off so that the text input changes. The second if is to make sure you flip only if needed.

Comment: Genius, thanks so much for this. It worked almost perfectly.. the only thing that didn't work was when you resign a keyboard, you loose the text in the UITextField - so I just had to cache that! I'll post the exact code I used in my question for others.

Answer (score 4):

`[textField reloadInputViews]` seems to do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

resignFirstResponder/becomeFirstResponder  & reloadInputViews have some caveats. See stackoverflow.com/questions/5958427/…. These change the keyboard back to its initial state. So if the user had toggled to one of the other keyboard layouts (numbers, punctuation, etc), that state will get lost. I've never found a good solution.